# Remove all symbols different from numbers and letters in string

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex that removes all symbols different from numbers and letters from string. Example:

```
string address = "TEXT 3 !@#$%^&*()_}|{:?> REMOVE ALL SYMBOLS 45";
string result = "TEXT 3 REMOVE ALL SYMBOLS 45";
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
var result = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]").Replace(address, string.Empty);
```

This keeps only whatever in `a-Z`, `A-Z` or `0-9` or `white space`

You can also use linq:

```
var result2 = new String(address.Where(x => char.IsLetterOrDigit(x) 
                                         || char.IsWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray());
```

Comment: The last '-': What is it for?

Comment: @PowerPuffGirl which one exactly ?

Comment: Why the down-vote ?

Comment: I was referring to a typo which is now no longer there.

Answer (score 3):

try this please

```
string address = "TEXT 3 !@#$%^&*()_}|{\":?> REMOVE ALL SYMBOLS 45";

var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var c in address)
{
    if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
        sb.Append(c);
}

var result = sb.ToString();
```

It should be faster than regex.

Comment: Not sure if `if(c == ' ' || Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))...` wasn't better, now you also allow tab- or newline-characters which wasn't requested.

Comment: spaces also wasn't requested but they present in sample.. also we dont know should we think about oter cultures. So there are a lot of questions really :)

Answer (score 0):

Both worked for me.
My final code:

```
 var addressWithoutEmtySpacesMoreThanOne = Regex.Replace(address, @"\s+", " ");
 var result = new Regex("[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9 -]").Replace(addressWithoutEmtySpaces, "");
 customer.Address = result;
```